# I need to change the opacity value of an image using JavaScript when i mouse over it but my code isn't working

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, mouseover, opacity

I need the images opacity to increase when I mouse over and decrease when I mouse out and I need
this to be gradual and not instant as it would be with CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="test" src="space1.png" onmouseover="updateOpacity()"/>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            var element = document.getElementById('test');
            var opacity = element.style.opacity;
            
            function updateOpacity()
            {
                opacity = opacity += 0.2;
                
                if(opacity >= 1)
                {
                    // done
                    opacity = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.style.opacity = opacity; // this updates the opacity
                    setTimeout(function(){updateOpacity();}, 50); // 50 is the delay, 50milliseconds
                }
            }
        </stript>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo (`</stript>`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to support current IE, you can do this cleanly using [CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/):

#### HTML

```
<img id="test" src="space1.png"/>
```

#### CSS

```css
#test {
    transition: opacity 600ms;
    opacity: 0.35;
}

#test:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Obligatory jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/millimoose/uNeMg/

(For the sake of clarity and sanity I'm omitting the vendor prefixes and using [`-prefix-free`](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/).)

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery an option?

```
<img id="test" src="space1.png" style="opacity: 0.1;">

<script>
var delay = 500; //500ms
$("#test").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, delay);
}).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.1
    },  delay); 
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3PAy/